# Generating random integer between negative and positive range in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I'm trying to generate a random integer in the range of -2 and 5 using `round` and `rand` functions. I'm able to generate a random integer however it always returns a negative value and a zero.

```
round(rand(1)*-5)
```

Comment: "returns a negative value and a zero".  That's because you're multiplying a number between 0 and 1 by a negative number.  The output will always be negative.

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use randi

```
r = randi([-2 5],1)
```

[rand](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)

And if you want to do this only using `rand` and `round`
Try this: `r = round(rand(1)*7 - 2);`

Answer (score 0):

heres also a possible way of doing it:

```
% generate 1000 random integers between -2 and 5
R = ceil(rand(1000,1)*8)-3;

% display MIN / MAX
disp(min(R));
disp(max(R));
```

Comment: Note that this works because @thomas is using `ceil`, and therefore has to increase the factor by 1 (so is  using 8 instead of 7).
This works because rand() never generates a true 0 or 1. Otherwise if true 0 is generated, this formula will sometimes (with low probability) generate the number -3.